# Find a best way to search data structure string compare

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, data-structures

I have a question which data structure is the best for particular situation.

we have one string "AAAAAAAAAAA", and we want to know this string contain  in one data base column or not.

For example below database there is two column.

```
1. ID   2. Name
  1        A
  2        B
  3        C
.....
49581    AAAAAAAAAAA
```

if it's match then, return true if not false.

I know I can use `list<string>` but I don't think it's best way to searching

I want to know which data structure is best way to search in this case.

Comment: Are you searching in memory with c#, or in sql?

Comment: You are performing premature optimization. You are making your program run faster before you have it running correctly. "If it doesn’t work, it doesn’t matter how fast it doesn’t work." - Mich Ravera

Comment: - gunr2171 , first get lists in SQL then want to control that lists in C#.

Comment: Do you need to know the ID/IDs of the given string, or only whether it exists (true/false)?

Comment: @clear.choi, it would be better to do the searching in sql. Why pull every row in the table over just to search for a single row? (also, use @ replies to respond to someone)

Comment: Sphinxxx I need to get only true and false at this moment.

Comment: Similar question, almost a duplicate, same answer: "[Should I be concerned about .NET dictionary speed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1903245/76337)".

Comment: gunr2171 because they have lots of data to compare like 2000, then 2000 time connect to database I/O so I thinking to use data structure. And it could be Like search too then I believe that is more problem.

Comment: The time cost to get 2000 rows into your c# application will likely far outweigh the cost of anything you do with those 2000 rows in c#. You could do a linear search of 2000 rows and it would still be a tiny amount of time compared to your data acquisition cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `HashSet<string>` would be faster to search than a `List<string>` if you only need to know whether the string exists.

[HashSet<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

..or if you feel adventurous, creating a "ternary search tree" or a "trie" may be an option:

http://www.drdobbs.com/database/ternary-search-trees/184410528

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer, but note that if you have a hash table then for each hashed string in the column you can store the row number(s) that have that string in the hash table position for the string. So hashing is not just limited to determining whether the string exists in your column or not.