# Dictionary search by a few key column not all

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

i am not sure it is possible or not.

i want to build a dictionary with Multi column key(let's say 4). then search by a few columns(2 or 3).

code:

```
class keyset
{
     public keyset()
     {}

     public long sId;
     public long aId;
     public string Name;
     public string title;

}


Dictionary<keyset, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<keyset, string>();
```

Then i want to search by only a few column in the keyset:

```
case 1:    sid = 100  and  aid=200
case 2:    sid = 50  and name="John"
.......
```

how can i do this?

---

Ok i understand that is not possible.
I should use linq.

Then i want to know which structure will be faster:

plan A:  use dictionary

```
class keyset
{
     public keyset()
     {}

     public long sId;
     public long aId;
     public string Name;
     public string title;

}

Dictionary<keyset, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<keyset, string>();
```

plan B:  without dictionary

```
class data
{
     public data()
     {}

     public long sId;
     public long aId;
     public string Name;
     public string title;


     public string  Value;      <-------- 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is not a database, so, no, you can't do that.

On the other hand, a `DataSet` *is* meant to be an in-memory representation of something like a database. If you use `DataSet` instead of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, then you'll be able to use the `Find` method to find the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a common logic for comparing `keysets` you can implement `IEquatable<T>` in your class. But if you want to compare them based on different properties each time this is not an option.In that case you can try using `LINQ`:

```
var itemExists = myDictionary.Any(x => x.Key.sid == 50 && x.Key.name == "John");

if(itemExists)
{
   var value = myDictionary.First(x => x.Key.sid == 50 && x.Key.name == "John").Value;
}
```

Comment: so is this the same speed if i just use linq then put "values" into same row without using a dictionary?

Comment: It's too soon to worry about performance. Worry about performance after the code works. "If it doesn't work, it doesn't matter how fast it doesn't work" — Mich Ravera. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1903245/76337